# php echo DOM Elements as strings

Tags: php, arrays, dom, getelementsbytagname

I have used the following code to store a small timetable in an array. I am trying to return specific elements of the array but get the error Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array.

I would be grateful if somebody could tell me how to retrieve the nodeValue of certain elements and display them.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($timetable);
$headers = $doc->getElementsByTagName('th');//' missed which is typo i think
$cells = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');//' missed which is typo i think
$array = iterator_to_array($cells);
```

I can loop through this and display the entire table with a for loop, and that's fine, but I can't return 1 value from the array:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++){
  $val = $array[$i];
  echo $val[1]->nodeValue;
}
```

And this returns the error I mentioned above.

Comment: what does this `iterator_to_array()` do? and how do the two code snippets relate to each other?

Comment: iterator_to_array() puts the $cells values into an array - it was something I googled to get my html elements into an array, it's possible there's a better way of doing it.

The second block of code I used for testing, and it worked, I thought it might be helpful/relevant to include it. It returns the whole html table. However I want to only return an element of it.

Comment: if `iterator_to_array` just takes the DOMNodeLIst from `getElementsByTagName` and "array-ifies" them, then probably you want `$val->nodeValue` instead. a dom node is NOT an array, and each of your `$val` would be a single node.

Comment: My thinking was that in order to retrieve specific nodeValue(s) from the dom elements, I would have to put them into an array so I can then access them. Is there a way of accessing them without this? I'm not clear on how your correction should be implemented in the code...

Comment: [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). It's basically an "array" (object that implements 'Traversable'), so you can literally just have `foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName(...) as $node) { ... }`

Comment: I see. And to access specific values within the DOMNodeList? With a foreach loop I can loop through the whole thing, but is there a way I can echo certain values?

Comment: just read the docs. that's explained too

Comment: Thank you Marc, it's all there in the docs, case closed, will post my solution :)